# Passing multiple parameter in app-engine Task Queue (JAVA)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, task-queue

Is there a way to pass multiple parameters in a Queue in google-app-engine?
I use the code below

```
Queue queue = QueueFactory.getQueue("sms-queue");
queue.add(TaskOptions.Builder.url("/SQ").param("id",pId));
```

in my servlet this id is retrievd as a query string.

```
long pID = Long.parseLong(req.getParameter("id"));
```

I need to pass 6 parameters.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have you tried doing this:

```
queue.add(TaskOptions.Builder
    .url("/SQ")
    .param("p1Name", p1Value)
    .param("p2Name", p2Value)
    .param("p3Name", p3Value)
    // etc
);
```