# How do I pass user credentials to a App Engine Task Queue servlet?

Tags: google-app-engine

Say you have a user who is authenticated via Google Accounts come in to your app at /run and then you need to spin off something in the default task queue for that user. Right now, that user's credentials are not carried over to the task servlet (e.g. /worker). Is there a way to pass them? Maybe by taking headers from the orig request and adding them to the Task Queue request?

Comment: are you trying to access user data offline?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing multiple parameter in app-engine Task Queue (JAVA)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3107565/passing-multiple-parameter-in-app-engine-task-queue-java)

Comment: Currently both answers are incorrect or add unneeded overhead. See the linked dup

Comment: I'm trying to send email via the logged in user. App Engine only allows sending of email From an admin associated with the app or the currently logged in user (simplified explanation I realize). I can send email as the logged in user if the code is in /run, but if I put it in /worker the credientials are not passed and i get an Unauthorized sender exception.

Comment: I looked at the possible duplicate of "Passing multiple parameters in app-engine Task Queue" but that really has nothing to do with my question --unless there is a way to pass the user credential on the URL (please explain if possible).

Answer (score -1):

If you're using Java Servlet, you can use this logic:

- After successfully sign in (using Google+ Sign In and Endpoint), store user credentials in HttpSession as attributes (Put HttpServletRequest in your Endpoint API as parameter, and just get the session).
- In your servlet logic, get the session, and retrieve the credential.

P.S. Don't forget to set `<sessions-enabled>true</sessions-enabled>` in your appengine-web.xml.

Answer (score -2):

Put user credentials into datastore from your app, and read them from datastore in your task.

Example user model in Python with ndb and oauth2client:

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
from oauth2client import appengine

class User(ndb.Model):
    # among other user props
    credentials = appengine.CredentialsNDBProperty()
```